# Laravel Grouping by Eloquent Relationship

Tags: laravel, relation

How can I group by relation?

Example

```
Sales::with('product_detail.product')->groupBy('product_name')->get()
```

How can I get a result with eloquent code?

Comment: Was this solved yet?

Answer (score 19):

You can specify a callback function for grouping your relation like this:

```
Sales::with(['product_detail.product' => function($query){
        $query->groupBy('product_name');
    }])->get();
```

Comment: Since the relationship is pulled in with a separate query and not a join, this does not do what OP was asking for.

Answer (score 12):

I think the top answer is not answering the question. As I understand, the aim is to group the results of the outer query, not the relationship.

This is not possible in an Eloquent-y DB call because the call for the With is separate. You can manually join the tables and group by the required column.

If you want to stay Eloquent-y, there are many convenient methods available to Collections, including GroupBy. So you can get the data first and group later.

Comment: Hey Sahil, any chance you could supply a line of code or example that may be useful to the asked question?

Answer (score 6):

This may already be old but yeah, it can help a seeker.

You can chain directly to relationships/distant relationships with groupBy in Laravel. I don't know if this is specific to any version but V8 works. And the relationship is loaded as well like you would use `with`.

```
 Sales::query()->where('this', $that)->get()->groupBy('product.name'); // OR

 Sales::query()->where('this', $that)->get()->groupBy('product.status.name');
```

Comment: you were right it did help a seeker :)

Comment: It's worth noting that this is a completely different `groupBy` method than the one in the question. It's working on a collection, not a database query.

Comment: I cannot get this to work, is this documented?

Comment: @joey-carlisle yes, documentation is under Collections, not Eloquent https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-groupby

Comment: this worked for me, thanks @Lekia

Answer (score 0):

laravel >= 7 you can use:

In **controller**

```
$user->sales()->groupBy('product_name')->get();
```

In **User.php** file :

```
public function sales(){
     return $this->hasMany('App\Sales','user_id');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This question requires more information - sure, you can do:

```
Sales::with('productDetail.product')
->leftJoin('product_details', 'sales.product_details_id', '=', 'product_details.id')
->leftJoin('products', 'product_details.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
->groupBy('products.product_name')->get()
```

but doing this will still result in one `Sales` model for each row. So, for example, given two `sales` rows in DB, pointing through two `product_details` rows to one row for `products` (two different customers bought same Product) will result in one `Sales` model. Or, if one customer bought two Products (if `product_details` is a pivot table with `sales_id` and `products_id`) will result in two identical `Sales` models being returned.

Suming it up - you can, but you shouldn't

Answer (score -3):

Group by distant relation:

```
Sales::select(DB::raw('count(*) as count'), 'products.name')
  ->join('product_details', 'sales.product_detail_id', '=', 'product_details.id')
  ->join('products', 'product_details.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
  ->groupBy('products.name')
  ->get();
```