# Laravel Group & Count by Eloquent Relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I know this question has be asked before here: [Laravel Grouping by Eloquent Relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36468759/laravel-grouping-by-eloquent-relationship) but the answers are from 2016 and they seem not to work in 2019. Also my question is more simple, since I only need one relation level.

**My Question**

A
 **user** has multiple **items**.
 How to find how many `items` a user has of each `item_type` with one query?

---

***This is what I tried:***

A query like

```
User::with(['items' => function($q){
  $q->groupBy('type');
});
```

returns this error:

> Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list
>   is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'items.id'
>   which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause;
>   this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

I tried to fix this error with the following query:

```
User::with(['items' => function($q){
    $q->select('type', \DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
          ->groupBy('type');
});
```

However, this returns a collection of `users` where each user's `item` collection is empty.

Is it somehow possible to group by a relation in the query?

Answer (score 3):

There is an error :

You are using $q as closure argument and inside you are using $query. Also sometimes I have faced issue where I had to pass the foreign key inside the relation query closure to get the results :

```
<?php 

$userWithItems = User::with(['items' => function($q){
    $q->select('type', \DB::raw('count(*) as total'), 'user_id')
          ->groupBy('type');
});
```

Try it once by removing user_id if it works then it's better. Secondly you can not select non aggregated columns in mysql when you have groupby. The option is disable `only_full_group_by` in mysql configurations. So mostl likely user_id will also fail unless you disable this configuration

Comment: Thanks for spotting the typo, I corrected it. I think your right when I would add the foreignt key it would work. However, I do not want to disable `only_full_group_by`. But thanks anyway