# Laravel Grouping Many to Many relationships

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have 2 tables

```
Users :  
id
name
```

```
Roles :
id
name
```

These two tables have a many to many relationship with the pivot table

```
Role_user : 
role_id
user_id
```

How do I group all users by role name? I tried this but it seems to work only for one to many relationships

```
User::with('roles')->get()->groupBy('roles.name');
```

[Something like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAzNW.png)

Comment: *How do I group all users by role name?* What do you mean? return users list as one CSV for each group? return users sorted by groups? something else?

Comment: For example I want to group users who are admins on one hand and users with a normal role on the other hand

Comment: then you may use the Role model instead of User model for that

Comment: @jerson look at the image

Comment: so you mean that user will be group by many role?

Comment: Yeah that's exactly it

Comment: As a lot of other questions I read, it's not possible in Eloquent. You'll have to get the data and then use a loop over them to group. You can check: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/laravel-5-group-by-relationships-column OR https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36468759/laravel-grouping-by-eloquent-relationship

Comment: use `groupBy` before `get` function.

Comment: yet this request works for one to many relationships `User::with('role')->get()->groupBy('role.name');`

Comment: It's answered here
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70549220/how-to-groupby-many-to-many-relationships-in-laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70549220/how-to-groupby-many-to-many-relationships-in-laravel)