# How to groupBy many to many relationships in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database, eloquent

I have this basic database model **I would like to group all users by role name** i.e. I want to list the users who are admins and the others in two collections.

Database model

[image]

I tried to do this but it only works for one to many relationships

```
User::with('roles’)->get()->groupBy(‘roles.name’);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use wildcard `*` to skip an array:

```
User::with('roles')->get()->groupBy('roles.*.name');
```

Comment: Little explanation what the wildcard (*) is skipping would be nice.

Comment: suppose that the pivot table role_user contains a column 'type'. How can we group the users by this column?

Comment: @AhmedIbrahimMeraneh add `->withPivot('type')` to  `roles` relationship of `User` model and use `groupBy('roles.*.pivot.type')`